# Choosing between two sets of tootips

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

Working with the vbnet form editor, I have instancied 2 times the tooltip class: one for English Langage, one for French langage. (you can also imagine: short version /extended version)
How to choose dynamically between the to instancies at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to handle the topic:

```
Private Sub Tip_En_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tip_En.CheckedChanged
    If Tip_En.Enabled Then
        Me.ToolTip_Fr.Active = False
        Me.ToolTip_en.Active = True
    End If
    ToolTip_en.IsBalloon = True
End Sub

Private Sub Tip_Fr_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Tip_Fr.CheckedChanged
    If Tip_Fr.Enabled Then
        Me.ToolTip_en.Active = False
        Me.ToolTip_Fr.Active = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Could surely be shortened and factorized...

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 instance, only changing the text displayed at runtime.

You can use an extra class like ToolTipTranslationTexts that holds all the text translations after setting a language this class knows what language you have set.

Put a method like PopulateToolTipText into it, from which you change all tooltip texts to the right language. 
This is one approach I could think off, but there are many more.

That way you can also add more languages only by adding text to this class.